# How create a String value for represent some values in select results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, replace

In my Select i have this result:

```
name | type |
-----+------+
booo | A    |
xooo | B    |
dooo | A    |
```

I need a way in SQL SERVER to replace A for "Abstract" and B for "Ball"
Thanks,
Celso

Comment: This is very unclear. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH Strings(type,description)
AS
(
SELECT 'A', 'Abstract' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'Ball' 
)
SELECT y.foo, s.description
FROM YourTable y
JOIN Strings S ON S.type = y.type
```

Answer (score 3):

Create another table with this mapping and use joins.

```
type | long_name |
-----+-----------+
  A  | Abstract  |
  B  | Ball      |
  C  | Cat       |
```

Comment: +1 A permanent table indexed on `type` should be more efficient than a CTE and be more generally useful.

Answer (score 1):

You also might look at the CASE function in SQL Server, depending on what you're trying to do.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 0):

select name as "name",

```
   (case type
    when 'A' then 'Abstract'
    when 'B' then 'Ball'
    end) as "Type"
```

from MyTable

order by name